# std::bind and std::function questions

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int func(int x){return x;}
...
std::function<int(int)> x = std::bind(func, std::placeholders::_1);
x(123);
```

1. Does `x(123)` actually call the `operator()` of the functor which `std::function` generated which in turn calls the `operator()` of the functor which `std::bind` generated which finally calls `func`? Does this get optimized into something as optimal as calling `func(123)`?
2. Where does the functor live which `std::bind` generates? In what scope? And how does `std::bind` name it? (can there be name collisions)
3. Can lambdas replace all uses of `std::bind`?
4. Is `std::bind` as optimal as implementing it as a lambda instead?
5. What's up with the syntax of the template argument of `std::function`? How does that get parsed and how can I use that template argument syntax elsewhere?

Comment: For 2. you might be interested in http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Comment: One question at a time, please. Each SO post is a question.

Comment: This is more of a set of questions than a concrete question, and they range from syntax (for the argument of `function<>`) to behavior (where does the result of bind live? can lambda substitute them?) performance (will it be optimized?)

Comment: For 1. Unfortunately as far as I remember(seeing generated code by VS2012 - release) it does not compare at all with x(123) call. For example, it's not in-lined. If you use a lambda you have inlineing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does x(123) actually call the operator() of the functor which std::function generated which in turn calls the operator() of the functor which std::bind generated which finally calls func? Does this get optimized into something as optimal as calling func(123)?

I wouldn't describe the `operator()` of `std::function` as 'generated' (it's a regular member), but otherwise that is a good description. Optimizations are up to your compiler, but be warned that to optimize the indirection of `std::function` (which requires the use of type erasure) a compiler may need to perform heroics.

> Where does the functor live which std::bind generates? In what scope? And how does std::bind name it? (can there be name collisions)

The call to `std::bind` returns a functor of unspecified type, and a copy of that functor is stored inside the `x` object. This copy will live as long as `x` itself. There is no name involved so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

> Can lambdas replace all uses of std::bind?

No. Consider `auto bound = std::bind(functor, _1);` where `functor` is a type with an overloaded `operator()`, let's say on `long` and `int`. Then `bound(0L)` doesn't have the same effect as `bound(0)` and you can't replicate that with a lambda.

> Is std::bind as optimal as implementing it as a lambda instead?

This is up to the compiler. Measure yourself.

> What's up with the syntax of the template argument of std::function? How does that get parsed and how can I use that template argument syntax elsewhere?

It's a function type. Perhaps you're already familiar with the syntax for pointers/references to functions: `void(*)()`, `int(&)(double)`. Then just remove the pointer/reference out of the type, and you just have a function type: `void()`, `int(double)`. You can use those like so:

```
typedef int* function_type(long);
function_type* p; // pointer to function
```

Comment: +1 for the only correct answer to question #2: a functor is just an object, there is no magical class generation involved.

Comment: Nailed the static polymorphism (bind) vs. monomorhic prototypes (function<>) difference the first time round :) Quite a profound but easily overlooked difference indeed. (You had my +1 from the start)

Comment: +1 for the use case of `bind` that cannot be replicated with lambda.

Answer (score 6):

> **1 .** Does `x(123)` actually call the `operator()` of the functor which `std::function` generated which in turn calls the `operator()` of the functor which `std::bind` generated which finally calls `func`? Does this get optimized into something as optimal as calling `func(123)`?

If you have optimizations enabled, the 'stuff' gets inlined and you can count on this being as optimal as calling `func(123)`.

> **2 .** Where does the functor live which `std::bind` generates? In what scope? And how does `std::bind` name it? (can there be name collisions)

Precising: `bind` generates a 'fleeting', implementation defined, bind expression, that is assignable to `function<>`. Function is just a class template (Thanks, Luc T.). And it lives in the standard library. However, the bind expressions are implementation defined.

The standard library *does* come with traits ([`std::is_bind_expression<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981965.aspx)) to allow MPL detection of such expressions. One decisive feature of bind expressions over std::function is that they are (what I'd call) *deferred callable objects* (i.e. that they retain full call site semantics including the ability to select overloads at the actual application site). `std::function<>`, on the other hand, commits to a single prototype and internally stores the [*callable object*](http://drdobbs.com/184401949) by type erasure (*think `variant` or `any`*).

> **3 .** Can lambdas replace all uses of std::bind?
>
> **4 .** Is std::bind as optimal as implementing it as a lambda instead?

AFAICT lambdas should compile down to about the same as the bind expressions. One thing that I *think* lambdas can't do that bind expressions *can* is **[*`nested bind expressions`*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds)** 
**Edit** While the specific idiom of nested bind expressions is not replicatable using lambdas, lambdas are of course able to express (nearly) the same much more naturally:

```
 bind(f, bind(g, _1))(x); 
 // vs.
 [](int x) { f(g(x)); };
```

> **5 .** What's up with the syntax of the template argument of `std::function`? How does that get parsed and how can I use that template argument syntax elsewhere?

It is just a function signature (the *type* of a function), being passed as template parameter.

You can also use it as a function parameter type, which *degrades* to a function pointer(similar to how array by-value parameters degrade to pointers, Thanks David!). 
In practice, most anywhere, as long as you don't have a need to *name* a variable/type:

```
 void receiveFunction(void(int, double)); // spunky 'function<>'-style syntax

 void sample(int, double) { } 

 int main()
 { 
     receiveFunction(sample);
 }

 void receiveFunction(void (*f)(int, double)) // boring 'old' style syntax
 //                   void ( f)(int, double)  // ... also ok
 {
     // ..
 }
```

Comment: Assuming `f` and `g` are not overloaded, then the nested bind expression can be expressed as a lambda: `[](T t) { return f(g(t)); }`.

Comment: @LucDanton: found the info in your answer. +1 for that

Comment: I disagree on point 2: the correct answer is that there is no functor "generated" by `bind`, just a temporary object returned by a function, which has no name and will live for the time of the expression it appears in (like all temporaries). This temporary is used to initialize `x`.

Comment: The only thing that is not specified is the type of the object returned, all we know is that it must meet a set of requirements: it must be move-constructible, invokable with a given set of arguments, etc.

Comment: +1, but *it is just a function signature, being parsed as the type of a function pointer*... The **pointer** part is wrong, the type is the signature of a function, and it does not get parsed as a pointer, but as a signature (from which the arguments are extracted to generate the signature of `operator()`, no pointers involved in the whole process). As of your later example, the deal is that in a function declaration the type *function ...* is transformed to *pointer to function* in the same way that *array of* decays into *pointer to the first element*, but...

Comment: ... but the type of a function pointer and a function are different. You can, for example, use a typedef of a function to *declare* a function in your code: `typedef void func(int); func f;` declares `void f(int);`... there are other differences

Comment: on the lambdas not being able to emulate *nested bind expressions*, they can do it and quite trivially. For your particular example: `[]( int x ) { f(g(x)); }` which is actually more readable...

Comment: Re: point 1, "*If you have optimizations enabled, the 'stuff' gets inlined and you can count on this being as optimal as calling func(123).*" I entirely disagree -- `std::function<>` uses type-erasure internally, and inlining cannot occur through type erasure. I.e., invoking a bind expression directly can be trivially inlined, but invoking a `std::function<>` can never inline the original function/functor. Re: nested bind expressions, I think that behavior is specific to `boost::bind` and doesn't apply to `std::bind`, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Wow. I love stack overflow. Where else would you learn so much by _answering questions_. Apologies for any errors committed by me, and I'm honoured by your great additions. I have rewritten the answer to **2.** (referencing `std::is_bind_expression` now and describing _deferred callable object_ semantics). I've updated the wording on _function types_ vs. _function pointers_ (Thx David) I'll spend some time cleaning up the rest, too. Again, I'm so very happy that you have taken the time to report all these (little) points. It is humbling, but there is no place quite like SO for learning C++11 !

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Re "nested binds - boost specific?" I remember reading on nested binds for the first time in Pete Beckers book, and at least VS2010 supports nested `std::bind`s (with some bugs)

Answer (score 0):

> Can lambdas replace all uses of std::bind?

C++14 will allow lambdas to mostly replace bind. Responding in particular to Luc Danton's answer, in C++14, you can write templated lambdas using auto such that `bound(0)` and `bound(0L)` behave differently.